# VBA 1D array ("array or user defined type expected")

Tags: arrays, vba, compiler-errors

I need to make an array of numbers from "n" to "n2" to use it in an IF function like

```
If ArrayContainsItem([transpose(row(320:420))], WidthArray) Then
    'Do stuff
End If
```

And I am wondering, how do you write that first array (which must be written inside that line directly and not dimensioned prior)? It returns an error "array or user-defined type expected"

I got it working with

```
dim arr() as variant
arr = [transpose(row(320:420))]

'Main function
If ArrayContainsItem(arr, WidthArray) Then
    'Do stuff   
End If

End Sub
```

But I need it to be made up directly inside the if function line like in the first code example.

The function I am using looks like (can't be altered in any way)

```
Function ArrayContainsItem(ArrayBig() As Variant, ArraySmall() As Variant) As Boolean

'Declare variables
Dim iOption As Long

'Set variables
ArrayContainsItem = False

'Main function
For iOption = 2 To UBound(ArraySmall)

    For Each Item In ArrayBig
        If CStr(Item) = ArraySmall(iOption) Then
            ArrayContainsItem = True
        End If
    Next Item    
    ArrayContainsItem = False
Next iOption

End Function
```

Changing the function to

```
Function ArrayContainsItem(ArrayBig As Variant, ArraySmall() As Variant)
```

returns error 2015 on ArrayBig and item is empty.

Would, someone, please help me figure this one out?

Reproducable example

```
Sub ArrayTesting()

'Old variables
Dim WS_MS As Worksheet
Set WS_MS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification")
Dim LowerFilmWidthArray() As Variant
Dim CurrentParameter As Range
Dim ParametersColumn As Long
ParametersColumn = 2
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = 4


'Width
Set CurrentParameter = WS_MS.Cells.Find("Width", lookat:=xlWhole)
WidthArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(WS_MS.Range(Cells(CurrentParameter.Row, ParametersColumn), Cells(CurrentParameter.Row, LastColumn)).Value))


'Main function
If ArrayContainsItem([transpose(row320:420)], WidthArray) Then
    
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please create a [reprex], including sample values for  `WidthArray`. Also why are you `CStr` within `ArrayContainsItem`, that seems suspect? Also you probably need `Exit Function` after `ArrayContainsItem = True`. Also, _But I need it to be made up directly inside the if function line like in the first code example_... why? Why are you imposing this restriction?

Comment: The function which "can't be altered in any way" looks wrong, anyhow. It will always return `False`, independent of what the small array contains. Then, you should show us what it contains. What does the function in discussion should check? If all the small function elements match the Big one? If so, why the iteration starts from 2? Only one of its elements matches? If so, it should be structured in a different way. For both cases...

Comment: `For Each Item In ArrayBig` - one normally would use `LBound` and `UBound` and a regular `For` loop to iterate an array, not a `For Each` loop.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a reproduceable example. We don't have your workbook, so your code is not runnable. Please create a reproduceable example of `WidthArray`, either with sample data as text that we can paste into an Excel sheet, or a code snippet that recreates it.

Comment: well You need CStr so that those numbers from the generated array would match an item from width array taken as a string from the worksheet. Also don't worry about the functionality of teh function, taht is not the problem I am having)

Comment: But what problem do you **really** have? The result of `Evaluate` cannot be directly cast to a **`Variant` array**. Only `Variant` may accept the way you want. Why? Because this is the way VBA works....

Comment: I need "[transpose(row320:420)]" (an array of numbers from 320 to 420 one by one) to work in a line like "If ArrayContainsItem([transpose(row320:420)], WidthArray) Then" and NOT give me an error saying "array or user defined type expected" or any other error

Comment: My question is not about the functionality of the function nor what it returns... I know it's not correct and it's besides the point of the question

Answer (score 1):

Change your function declaration:

```
Function ArrayContainsItem(ArrayBig() As Variant, ArraySmall() As Variant) As Boolean
```

to

```
Function ArrayContainsItem(ArrayBig As Variant, ArraySmall() As Variant) As Boolean
```

---

Sample:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim arraySmall(1 To 3) As Variant
    arraySmall(1) = "foo"
    arraySmall(2) = "bar"
    arraySmall(3) = "baz"
        
    Debug.Print ArrayContainsItem([transpose(row(320:420))], arraySmall) ' Returns False

    arraySmall(1) = "1"
    arraySmall(2) = "2"
    arraySmall(3) = "420"
    
    Debug.Print ArrayContainsItem([transpose(row(320:420))], arraySmall) ' Returns True
End Sub

Function ArrayContainsItem(ArrayBig As Variant, arraySmall() As Variant) As Boolean

    'Declare variables
    Dim iOption As Long
    
    'Main function
    For iOption = 2 To UBound(arraySmall)
    
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(ArrayBig) To UBound(ArrayBig)
            If CStr(ArrayBig(i)) = arraySmall(iOption) Then
                ArrayContainsItem = True
                Exit Function '<-- add this
            End If
        Next
    Next iOption

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it's not too helpful without an exact example. Can't get the syntax right with this :(

Comment: Here you go, mate :)

Comment: I specifically mentioned that function "can't be altered in any way". I use the same function for all my arrays and this type with the generated numbers array is the only one that is causing issues

Comment: It should work just fine as a `Variant` instead of a variant array.

Comment: It does not work even with this one unfortunately giving error 2015 on arraybig

Comment: Literally doing what your answer suggested :)

Comment: Can't tell what you're actually using as `WidthArray` tho, so you don't have a [reprex].

Comment: It's an array transposed from a values in a row and works perfectly :)